# Как сохранить измененные ширины столбцов таблицы в БД

Tags: php, html, jquery, база-данных

В общем дело обстоит в следующем, в [проекте](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LBsG/C9qaDYnNA) есть таблица Boootstrap, подключен [плагин](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/) "colresizable" чтобы была возможность вручную менять ширину столбцов таблицы. В СУБД **phpmyadmin** была создана БД "edit-table", а в ней таблица "table-width" (поля: id, table_name, cols_width).

Так вот, как можно сохранить изменененные ширины колонок таблицы Boootstrap в БД, чтобы при следующем открытии таблицы, она отображалась так как ее изменил пользователь?

Comment: При изменении сохранить в БД, при каждой загрузки страницы считать ширину з БД? Что у вас конкретно не получается?

Comment: 1) как собрать ширину всех колонок которые изменил пользователь

2)сохранить в бд

3)и при  следующем открытии таблицы подгружать ширину всех колонок из бд

Comment: В оф. доке (http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/) есть примеры. В примере "multiple range slider" при изменении колонок выводится информация о их соотношении. Будет вам как пример, чтобы собрать ширины всех колонок